# Don't print a message when a value is negative

Tags: c

I don't want to print `"The biggest integer is:"`  when I enter a negative value. However, my program prints both statements when I only want to print one or the other. I want to do it as a `do`-`while` statement. Please Help.

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main() {    
    int biggestnum;
    int i;    

    printf("Please enter an integer:");
    scanf("%d", &biggestnum);

    if (biggestnum < 0) {   
        printf("Didn't give me any data, goodbye.");
    } else
        do {
            printf("Please enter an integer:");
            scanf("%d", &i);

            if (i >= 0)
                if (i > biggestnum) {
                    biggestnum = i;
                }
        } while (i >= 0);

    printf("The biggest integer is: %d\n", biggestnum);

    return (0); 
}
```

Comment: I hope the reason is clearer with corrected indentation. The last `printf` is not inside the `else` code block – which has no `{` braces `}`.

Comment: I tried putting it inside the brackets before but the program wouldn't work properly. I am still a newbie at this. If you can show me the correct way, please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Aside: note the redundant `if (i >= 0)`. You already know that `biggestnum >= 0` and a negative value of `i` cannot be greater.

Comment: You need another set of `{`braces`}`. The opening **{** just after **else** – like `else {`. And the closing **}** just before **return** – like `} return 0;`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! May I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about questions, answers and voting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add braces `{}` for your else statement ,otherwise after both `if (biggestnum<0)` and `else statement` (no matter which one is true) you will go to this line `printf("The biggest integer is: %d\n", biggestnum);` and then `return 0`.

look

```
int main() {

    int biggestnum;
    int i;

    printf("Please enter an integer:");
    scanf("%d", &biggestnum);

    if (biggestnum < 0) {
        printf("Didn't give me any data, goodbye.");
    }
    else
    {
        do {
            printf("Please enter an integer:");
            scanf("%d", &i);

            if (i >= 0)
                if (i > biggestnum) {
                    biggestnum = i;
                }

        } while (i >= 0);

        printf("The biggest integer is: %d\n", biggestnum);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a do-while loop, which isn't necessary while comparing 2 numbers,as it is redundant. I've attached a code beneath that has omitted it with certain corrections (indentations,curly brackets,etc):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{    
    int biggestnum,i;    
    printf("Please enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%d",&biggestnum);
    if (biggestnum<0)
    {  
       printf("Didn't give me any data, goodbye.\n");
    }
    else
        {
            printf("Please enter an integer: \n");
            scanf("%d",&i);
            if(i>=0)
                {
                    if(i>biggestnum)
                    {
                        biggestnum=i;
                    }
                }
            printf("The biggest integer is: %d\n", biggestnum);
        }
    return (0); 
}
```